# Deploying a custom ASMX service to a SharePoint 2007 Farm

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint, sharepoint-2007, asmx

I have an asmx web service that I need to install on a five server SharePoint 2007 farm with three front end web servers. I was able to develop and successfully deploy the web-service on a single SharePoint 2007 test server in the /_vti_bin along with the other SharePoint services.It works great, however it will not work on the Farm servers.

I have looked and I can not find any information about deploying custom web-services to SharePoint server farms. I have copied the same files into all three of the front end web servers and tried to change a bunch of things with no results. I have had fiddler open while I made the request to the service on the farm and I am getting a 401 error. I am not even sure why it is getting the error as the site is setup to allow anonymous access.

Comment: I believe that for SharePoint 2010, you can create a solution containing a feature that contains the .asmx file and any necessary web.config changes. That can be deployed to the farm and will go to each server. Doesn't something similar work on SharePoint 2007? How are you deploying now? Manually?

Comment: I have it configured to deploy as a wsp package solution so it is deploying to the correct places. It seems like the issue is related to the Farm setup. I can not find an example or any information on setting up custom web-services in a SharePoint 2007 farm environment.

Comment: The issue turned out to a group policy that was incorrectly applied to the service account that the service was running under. The policy was forcing the user account to use a non-existent proxy server. Which I only discovered after logging into the server under that user account.